# Moshi - Not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have an app which is mixed Java and Kotlin.
In the Kotlin code I use Moshi to convert an object to Json in a convertor for a Room database table.

I have one case that works perfectly but another one produces the error:

```
Not enough information to infer type variable T
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
        val type: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(
        MutableMap::class.java,
        LayerTwoConn::class.java,
        TWeFiState::class.java,
        WfMeasureFileMgr::class.java,
        Traffic::class.java,
        ThroughputCalculator::class.java,
        CellSubTechThroughput::class.java,
        LongValuesAverageCalculator::class.java,
        LayerTwoConn.SenselessTraffic::class.java
    )

    val json = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(type).toJson(layerTwoConn)
```

I have included all the classes that are used in the objects.
What have I missed?

This case works perfectly:

```
        val type: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(
        MutableList::class.java,
        CnrScan::class.java,
    )
    val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<List<CnrScan>> = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(type)

    val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(list)
```

In this object, all the internally used classes are standard Java class and not my own.

Have I missed something simple?

I don't know if this is important but the class LayerTwoConn's constructor is private.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to convert too many classes into one type, try to convert MutableMap class and LayerTwoConn class.
Do note that Room uses SQL architecture, so try to predict what you want your table to contain

Comment: I can't do just a subset because there is a deep structure to these classes

Comment: Why not build simple tables and use inner join to bridge the data?

Comment: SQL tables can't get objects into it - only varchars/ integer etc

Comment: It's too complicated to have the inner tables. Weird thing is it seems to have fixed itself. Not sure what happened.